# Copy Files /w Spaces In Name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My code is

```
SET usb="%CD%\Dokument\%USERNAME%\"
mkdir %usb%
for /R "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\" %%f in (*.docx) do copy %%f %CD%\Document\%USERNAME%\
```

and it works, but not for files (.docx) with spaces in their name.
I've tried fixing it with quotes, and different code styles/methods, but can't solve it. (I'm new to DOS).
How can I solve this?

Or is there a better code to copy all the files with .docx extension from a computer to another directory/usb?

Comment: this would have no chance to run in DOS. You meant `cmd`.  And quoting *is*  the way to go. Show your attempts, you probably did just a little mistake.

Comment: Oh, my bad. And, I basically saved it as a .bat, and ran it. It worked (copied all .docx files), but when it came to the files with spaces it their names, it says "file cannot be found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote file paths containing spaces, i.e. `copy "%%f"`

This may do what you wanted:

```bat
Set "USB=%~dp0Dokument\%USERNAME%"
If Not Exist "%USB%\" MD "%USB%" 2>&1||Exit/B
For /F "Delims=" %%A IN ('Where/R "%USERPROFILE%" *.docx'
) Do Copy/Y "%%A" "%USB%">Nul
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you.
Is there any chance you could explain what each part does? So I can learn :P
Cheers.

Comment: Using `%~dp0` means the current directory of this .bat file script. That might not be what the OP intended. If this .bat file script is in the `PATH`, it might be that the OP wants the `Dokument` directory in the current directory and not the directory where the .bat file script is located.

Comment: @lit, my assumption was this type of script would reside on the USB drive. The reply suggests my assumption well founded.