# batch script can't copy fine in a folder containing a space

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch code

```
copy H:\test\Folder\sample.ini H:\test\sample.ini
```

Pretty straight forward. However, it doesn't work if I modify the code to look in "New Folder" instead of "Folder".

In other words, I get a "file cannot be found error" if the directory structure contains a space. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy Files /w Spaces In Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392473/copy-files-w-spaces-in-name)

Comment: Something like this: `@If exist "H:\test\Folder\sample.ini" Copy /Y "H:\test\Folder\sample.ini" "H:\test"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it Doesn't work because there is a space in your Directory name(i.e New Folder) and it confuses windows interpreter,so all you have to do is add "" around your path.the following code should do your job:

```
COPY /Y "H:\test\New folder\sample.ini" "H:\test\sample.ini"
```